# Free oracle ERD tool

Tags: oracle, erd

are any free ERD tools for oracle out there?
Especially, I need some which can guess relations based on colum names (so if in one table a colum is named CO_ID and in an other table too, this should marked as a relation)

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse engineer (oracle) schema to ERD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503/reverse-engineer-oracle-schema-to-erd)

Comment: I don't know of any data modelling tool which can guess at foreign key relationships.  Frequently tables have columns like COMMENTS, DATE_CREATED, etc which would spawn lots of false positives.  However, you can use the Oracle data dictionary (specifically ALL_TAB_COLUMNS) to find tables which share common column names.  And from that list you could generate some DDL to create foreign key relationships.

Comment: Try https://www.erdcloud.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Oracle Datamodeler
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/downloads/datamodeler-087275.html